# My sql Group By case for getting highest paid employee in specific year

Tags: mysql, database, join, group-by, having-clause

there is two table
1 Employee
2 salary

```
Employee : eId, ename, salaryId
Salary : salaryId, eId, salary, date
```

salary table contains monthly record of employee salary,
like:

### eId date salary

```
1       2015-jan-01    10000
1       2015-feb-01    10000
1       2015-mar-01    10000
1       2014-jan-01    10000
1       2014-feb-01    10000
1       2014-mar-01    10000
2       2015-jan-01    10000
2       2015-feb-01    10000
2       2015-mar-01    10000
2       2014-jan-01    10000
2       2014-feb-01    10000
2       2014-mar-01    20000
```

so the query is to give me highest paid employee in specific year for ex: 2014

so here using group by  with date and sum of salary output is :

empid - empname  - sum(salary)
2     - xyz     - 40000

Comment: specify the dbms vendor please, you already have both Oracle and T-SQL answers and these might not be relevant for your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#highest paid emp in specific year
SELECT e.empId,e.empName,SUM(s.salary),s.salDate
FROM emp e INNER JOIN salary s ON e.empId = s.empId
WHERE YEAR(s.salDate)=2009 GROUP BY s.empId ORDER BY SUM(s.salary) DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: #delete duplicates for my notes
DELETE a  FROM testk a ,testk b WHERE a.name=b.name AND a.id> b.id;

Answer (score 1):

Try it with something like this ... i just took a glance to point you toward right direction, this query might need some fixing

```
Select TOP 1 emp.eid, emp.ename, sal.salary
from Employee emp 
join Salary sal on emp.salaryID = sal.salaryID
where DATEPART(yy,sal.date) =  2014
order by sal.salary desc
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work

```
with salaries as (
select to_char(date,'yyyy') y, eld, sum(salary) s_sal
from salary
group by to_char(date,'yyyy'), eld)

select eld
from salaries s
where s_sal = (select max(s_sal) from salaries where y=s.y)
and s.y='2014';
```

But you didn't specify DB, so there is Oracle syntax. 
And I didn't join with Employee table, but believe it isn't hard to add it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Code,

```
SELECT Top 1 E.ename         EmployeeName,
       MAX(salary)  AS EmployeeSalary
FROM   Employee E
       INNER JOIN Salary S
            ON  E.salaryID = S.salaryID
WHERE  YEAR(S.Date) = 2014
GROUP BY
       E.eId,
       E.ename
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to get the list of highest paid employee in each year then this can be achieved by a "Ranking" logic.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Year(SalaryMonthDate) AS [Payroll Year],
    EID, 
    Sum(Amout) AS [Annual Salary],
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Year(SalaryMonthDate) ORDER BY Sum(Amout) DESC) [Rank]
FROM tblSalary
GROUP BY Year(SalaryMonthDate), EID
```

Hope this helps.